# Annotation processor 'io.vertx.serviceproxy.ServiceProxyProcessor' not found

Tags: java, vert.x

http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-proxy/java/

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-service-proxy</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
  <classifier>processor</classifier>
</dependency>

<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessors>
      <annotationProcessor>io.vertx.serviceproxy.ServiceProxyProcessor</annotationProcessor>
    </annotationProcessors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

the `ServiceProxyProcessor` is resolvable from IDE

**Do I miss something?**

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Annotation processor 'io.vertx.serviceproxy.ServiceProxyProcessor' not found

--

I still can do the job with

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal> <!-- see the "vertx-service-proxy" -->
                    </goals>
                    <!-- http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-core/lifecycles.html -->
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- source output directory -->
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Without specifying the `ServiceProxyProcessor`

But I'm not sure it is correct way of doing, given that it is not in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to configure the compiler plugin, a working example for the pom could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-service-proxy</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-codegen</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-service-proxy</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <classifier>processor</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: should the vertx-service-proxy be defined twice?

Comment: @ses it is not really twice notice that one is the normal jar while the last is the jar with the classifier `processor`